# Python Pandas dataframe "for"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm new with python & pandas, i am trying to build a little bot. Maybe somebody can help me:

i have this data in sqlite:

```
Table users
ID   name   surname    phone    timestamp
1    elon    mask      33333    2021-08-22 22:01 
2    elon    mask      33333    2021-08-22 22:02
3    elon    mask      33333    2021-08-22 22:03
4    ector   vik       44444    2021-08-22 22:01
5    ector   vik       44444    2021-08-22 22:02
............... etc.........
```

i get data from db 2 times and:
only column name by date (to have only one user name 1 time) and i save to CSV

```
listc = c.execute("SELECT Pair FROM users WHERE Timestamp = '"+time1min+"' ".format(',')) 
df_to_output = pd.DataFrame(listc)
df_to_output.to_csv("nameusers.csv", index=False)
```

now i get all data and trasform it in pd dataframe (i wrote it works more fast) without column ID.

df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * from users", con)
df.drop('ID', axis=1, inplace=True)

now if i retrive data by date and name

```
    #i declare timeframe 
timenow = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
    time1min = (datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes = -1)).isoformat(timespec='minutes', sep=' ')

# i declare name to find
t1 = (df.loc[df['name'] == 'elon'])
```

everything works good.

what i cannot understand is how to do a loop where i query all data for all rows of name (i create nameusers.csv with list of names).
i tried with

```
ListPair=pd.read_csv("nameusers.csv")
for row in Listnames.iterrows():
     t1 = (df.loc[df['name'] == '{row}'])
```

but i receive [] ... empty
maybe somebody can drive me.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the code as `for index, row in Listnames.iterrows():` and check it again.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is a some sort of name column in `nameusers.csv` try something like this:

```
dfONE = pd.DataFrame({'ID': {1: 'elon', 2: 'elon', 3: 'elon', 4: 'ector', 5: 'ector'},
 'name': {1: 'mask', 2: 'mask', 3: 'mask', 4: 'vik', 5: 'vik'},
 'surname': {1: 33333, 2: 33333, 3: 33333, 4: 44444, 5: 44444},
 'phone': {1: '2021-08-22',
  2: '2021-08-22',
  3: '2021-08-22',
  4: '2021-08-22',
  5: '2021-08-22'},
 'timestamp': {1: '22:01', 2: '22:02', 3: '22:03', 4: '22:01', 5: '22:02'}})

dfTWO = pd.DataFrame({'Name': {0: 'john', 1: 'harry', 2: 'mask'}, 'Col2': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}})

print(dfONE, '\n')
print(dfTWO, '\n')
print('# Using the "Name" (captial N) from dfTWO filter the "name" (lowercase N) column in dfONE ')
print(dfONE.loc[dfONE['name'].isin(dfTWO['Name'])])
```

**Output:**

```
      ID  name  surname       phone timestamp
1   elon  mask    33333  2021-08-22     22:01
2   elon  mask    33333  2021-08-22     22:02
3   elon  mask    33333  2021-08-22     22:03
4  ector   vik    44444  2021-08-22     22:01
5  ector   vik    44444  2021-08-22     22:02 

    Name Col2
0   john    a
1  harry    b
2   mask    c 

# Using the "Name" (captial N) from dfTWO filter the "name" (lowercase N) column in dfONE 
     ID  name  surname       phone timestamp
1  elon  mask    33333  2021-08-22     22:01
2  elon  mask    33333  2021-08-22     22:02
3  elon  mask    33333  2021-08-22     22:03
```